# How do you write "yi ga shi duo" (Wu dialect)?

Tags: characters, topolect, shanghainese

Either Han characters or a standard romanization would do. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the meaning?

Comment: It's a synonym or near-synonym of 一塌糊涂.

Comment: The most common iteration of this phrase should be 一天世界, yi tie si ga. Could it be some variant of this? Maybe some mix of 一天星斗 together?

Comment: Maybe it's 一界星斗?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**一界星斗**

[Wu Chinese Forums](https://wu-chinese.com/bbs/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3247)

> 对呀，我处就是“一天世界”、“一天星”，还有个近义词“一天星斗”，我怀疑这“一天星”就是从“一天星斗”这里转过來的。